# Elsa Workflow - How to implement plugin to populate a ActivityInput field of ActivityInputUIHints.CheckList type

Tags: elsa-workflows

I have a dropdown and CheckList in an activity. I figured out how to populate the dropdown dynamically.

I would also to like to populate the checklist from the selected value of dropdown. But I used the chrome tool and looked at the elements, and found out the CheckList is not easy to handle.
I googled around and did not find a good example.

How do I populate a checklist? Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

Regards and thanks Simeon

Comment: Have you resolved this, I have the same issue :|